# List some common metrics to analyze the atmospheric vertical motion?

Tags: meteorology, climate-models

Could you give me some basic understanding of how to analyze the atmospheric vertical motion? 
For example, could you list some basic metrics to diagnose the vertical motion? Like divergence, vertical velocity (Omega). I got these two proxies from the published papers. Are there other common metrics to analyze vertical motion? 
I am a hydrological guy and have not so much meteorological background.

Thank you so much.

BTW, I am sorry for my too general question, but I just wanna some common metrics to do vertical motion analysis. My research focus on extreme precipitation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am unsure if your question relates to Numerical Weather Prediction (NWP) or field-experiments. I would say divergence is one of the best variables to look at since vertical motion is both difficult to measure and to model. Also, some nowcasting models which includes a nudging method to increase precipitation intensity in the model, based on the observed intensity does this by nudging the divergence field directly, to generate more or less vertical motion.

Comment: some references would help. You may have experience in working in these areas but some links would help improve this answer

Comment: Also if you are going to be mentioning divergence - you could mention what values of divergence what pressure surfaces to look at and provide an example. Just some suggestions nothing more